# Unable to block application in ubuntu 20.x using dynamic udp/tcp ports

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp, udp, ufw

I am using Ubuntu 20.x  (Ubuntu desktop fresh install)  & want to block an application in the firewall (ufw). I am able to block ports and protocols but not a specific application. One application uses UDP port and one uses TCP ports & they are using dynamic ports. I am unable to block this application specifically in UFW.

Any help. The docs of Ubuntu to block application does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Neither ufw nor gufw can block network access application-dependent. But can block the port(s), that the program uses for access. Even you define application profiles again it will just block certain ports for network access.

So How can I block network access to certain apps? There are some other ways such as;

1. Using https://github.com/netblue30/firejail where runs the application inside the sandbox `firejail --net=none spamapp`
2. Using https://linuxcontainers.org it is hard to configure.
3. Using https://douaneapp.com/ But it has some issues such as kernel panic.
4. Using Iptables such as creating a new user group and block internet access belonging to the group.  `sudo -g block-internet spamapp.sh`
5. Using https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch it is still in development.

Comment: What are the most important services for Ubuntu desktop running? I have too many default system services running in background and I have a issue here of these services bypassing the ufw

Comment: There are many of them but to keep the system running you can list them by using this command systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running if some of the services are bypassing the ufw. Either you wrongly set up ports for that service in ufw or it is a security flaw. You can check ports for that service such as netstat -ltup | grep